# How do I find the equation for a semicircle with a radius of 2 on the x axis?

Tags: calculus

I'm doing a calculus project where we have to make a model of some graph rotated about the y axis. I am doing a fish bowl and I have most of it understood and ready. The only thing I'm not sure of is what the equation of the semicircle is if its center is at (0,1.5). I added a picture to help illustrate it. Thank you for your help. [Image of semicircle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQidm.jpg)

Comment: Sorry the center is at (0,1.5)

Comment: You didn't state that the radius was 2.  but the equation is $(y - 1.5)^2 + x^2 = 4$

Answer (score 3):

Equation of a semi-circle at the origin:
$y= (r^2-x^2)^{1/2}$

To translate this to centre (a, b):
$y = \sqrt{r^2 - (x - a)^2} + b$

The solution for your example SHOULD be:
$y=\sqrt{4-x^2}+1.5$

Except, it's not. The image attached shows this graph, but rotated 90 degrees clockwise.
To resolve this, I'm going to perform a refection in the line y=x. This can be done by swapping the x and y values as shown:
$x=\sqrt{4-y^2}+1.5$

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a circle has center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$, then its equation is
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2.$$

The equation for that semicircle is therefore
$$x^2+(y-1.5)^2 = 4,$$
with the restriction $x\geq 0$.
If you wish, you can rewrite this as
$$x = \sqrt{4-(y-1.5)^2},$$
where $y\in [-\frac{1}{2},3\frac{1}{2}]$.